# Yii CRUD Index filtering items by db item

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii

I just created a Model and a CRUD for mysql database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `issue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT;
```

It's all fine and dandy, but people can see each other's list on index.php?r=issue/index. I don't want that to happen, I want to filter the index list to search for all the posts by user and only show his posts.

How can I do that?

**EDIT1:**

This is the _view, where the list gets shown to everyone:

```
<?php
/* @var $this IssueController */
/* @var $data Issue */
?>

<div class="view">

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('title')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('description')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->description); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('priority')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->priority); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('status')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->status); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('user')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->user); ?>
<br />


</div>
```

**EDIT2:**

I inserted the code below, but I get an error when I'm logged in a valid user that has a post:

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->findAll('user LIKE \''.Yii::app()->user->name.'\'', array('title'=>$data->title))); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->findAll('user ='.Yii::app()->user->name, array('title'=>$data->title))); ?>
<br />
```

Error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

**EDIT3:**

I just realized my logic is wrong, if the user has more than 1 post this will not do, I need to use a foreach to extract the values and echo them, but still unsure how to do it.

**EDIT4 SOLVED IT**

Here's my new _view:

```
<?php $foundAll=$data->findAllByAttributes(array('title'=>$data->title, 'description'=>$data->description, 'priority'=>$data->priority, 'status'=>$data->status, 'user'=>Yii::app()->user->name));//,'user LIKE '.'\''.Yii::app()->user->name.'\'');

//then you need use like
foreach($foundAll As $found)
{
    echo "<b>".$data->getAttributeLabel('id')."</b>: ";
    echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($found['id']), array('view', 'id'=>$found['id']));
    echo "<br />";

    //here you need to use array, like this $found['userId'].
    echo "<b>".$data->getAttributeLabel('title')."</b>: ";
    echo "".$found['title']."";
    echo "<br />";

    echo "<b>".$data->getAttributeLabel('description')."</b>: ";
    echo "".$found['description']."";
    echo "<br />";

    echo "<b>".$data->getAttributeLabel('priority')."</b>: ";
    echo "".$found['priority']."";
    echo "<br />";

    echo "<b>".$data->getAttributeLabel('status')."</b>: ";
    echo "".$found['status']."";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: findByAttributes(array('user'=>'hisName') ??

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21178-findbyattributes-example/

Comment: I'm a little lost where to insert it, on the index this is where it gets called: `<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
 'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the controller (IssueController) or the model (Issue) and find a definition of the variable $dataProvider.
It looks like this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue');
```

Just change it to:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addSearchCondition('user', Yii::app()->user->name);
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue', 'criteria'=>$criteria);
```